# Pig job hangs on first failure

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I'm encountering a problem  with Pig and Oozie.
I have  pig script that tries to read data from non-existent table, so an exception happens in *initialize* method of *RecordReader* . And that is ok, it should occur ( as the table definitely doesn't exist).
The problem starts when such a script is launched via oozie on a multi-node hadoop cluster - after the first attempt job just hangs and does nothing until any other job is submitted to the cluster.
If launched via CMD (pig -f test.pig) it doesn't hang. It also doesn't hang if launched in local mode or on a single-node cluster(via CMD or via Oozie).
I really hope someone had a problem like this and can help me.

Comment: please share your oozie config file

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu http://rgho.st/8tXh45pym Here is oozie config

Comment: not able to access this ? can you post a image of this ?

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu try this one - it should be definitely available for you https://github.com/xardazz/tmp/blob/master/conf.zip
config is pretty big to post it as images

Comment: can you post your workflow.xml file ? do you still have this issue ?

Comment: Is the pig job hanging or the oozie job (perhaps it is waiting for the trigger?) -- If you do launch 'any other job to the cluster' what happens then? -- Is it a problem that your job takes some time to fail?